# Open multiple workbooks and activate specific workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have multiple workbooks and I'm simply trying to activate a specific workbook and keep getting an error, stating `"object doesnt support this property or method."`

Code below:

```
Sub RUNME()

'Call OPENFiles 'this call runs a small piece of code to open all the files an works fine


Dim wbmacro As Workbook
Dim wblean As Workbook
Dim wbmain As Workbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet


Set wbmacro = Workbooks.Item("MacroFile.xlsm")
Set wbmain = Workbooks.Item("Mainfile.csv")
Set wblean = Workbooks.Item("Secondfile.csv")

Set ws1 = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Data")
Set ws3 = wblean.Worksheets.Item("Sheet2")

wblean.ws3.Activate 'line with error
```

I've tried playing with this a few different ways but don't understand why I'm getting this error?

Comment: `wblean` is already part of the worksheet variable.  so you only need `ws3.activate`

Comment: If you want to verify what I am saying just do `Debug.Print ws3.Parent.Name`

Comment: You should really avoid numeric suffixes like this. `macroDataSheet`, `mainSheet`, and `leanSheet` would be much more meaningful in context. Thank yourself later.

Comment: made the changes as above. thanks all!